# Maven:Including jars from remote repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I wish to include jars present under \10.171.98.23 system [ex:\10.171.98.23\workspace\Project\lib] in my pom.xml by making use of remote repository concept.
How it could be achieved in Maven?Any suggestions would be more useful to proceed

Comment: Start using a repository manager and put the wished jars' into it...and than use them as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example would be:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-internal-site</id>
      <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Check the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) for more détails. You could also have a look at [Maven the reference guide](https://www.sonatype.com/ebooks).